# does pthread_join affects concurrently

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I want to run all threads concurrently. If I use pthread_join function does it affect running of threads concurrently?

```
pthread_join(..)
```

Comment: `pthread_join` waits for a thread to complete (i.e. exit gracefully). It does not terminate the thread if that's what your're asking.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> ...does it affect running of threads concurrently?

That seems like a strange thing to ask. *Technically* speaking, Yes. Nothing in thread `A` can happen concurrently with anything in thread `B` after thread `A` calls `pthread_join(B, ...)`.

But that's an obscure, academic way to talk about `pthread_join()`. The *practical* way to say the same thing is, `pthread_join(B, ...)`, *does not return* until thread `B` is finished.